# Bouncy Castle provider throws NoSuchAlgorithmException while works in standard java

Tags: java, android, encryption, box

I am trying to implement box-java-sdk with jwt authentication in android. When sdk is trying to decrypt private key in these lines:

```
InputDecryptorProvider pkcs8Prov = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC")
                                   .build(this.privateKeyPassword.toCharArray());
PrivateKeyInfo keyInfo =  ((PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) keyPair).decryptPrivateKeyInfo(pkcs8Prov);
decryptedPrivateKey = (new JcaPEMKeyConverter()).getPrivateKey(keyInfo);
```

following exception is occuring:

```
W/System.err: com.box.sdk.BoxAPIException: Error parsing PKCS private key for Box Developer Edition.
W/System.err:     at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.decryptPrivateKey(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:516)
W/System.err:     at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.constructJWTAssertion(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:450)
W/System.err:     at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.constructJWTAssertion(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:431)
W/System.err:     at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.authenticate(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:320)
W/System.err:     at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.tryRestoreUsingAccessTokenCache(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:419)
W/System.err:     at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppUserConnection(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:271)
W/System.err:     at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppUserConnection(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:296)
W/System.err:     at com.kapalya.box.BoxClient$1.inBackgroud(BoxClient.java:41)
W/System.err:     at com.kapalya.box.BoxClient$4.doInBackground(BoxClient.java:111)
W/System.err:     at com.kapalya.box.BoxClient$4.doInBackground(BoxClient.java:107)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err: Caused by: org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13 not available: Provider BC does not provide 1.2.840.113549.3.7
W/System.err:     at org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.decryptPrivateKey(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:505)
W/System.err:   ... 15 more
W/System.err: Caused by: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13 not available: Provider BC does not provide 1.2.840.113549.3.7
W/System.err:     at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder$1.get(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:   ... 17 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Provider BC does not provide 1.2.840.113549.3.7
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.getCipher(Cipher.java:357)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:325)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:297)
W/System.err:     at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.util.NamedJcaJceHelper.createCipher(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:   ... 18 more
```

While this sdk is working fine in standard java app. Is there any change in android's implementation of BountyCastle provider ? Is there a workaround for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by first removing android implementation of BountyCastle :

```
Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
```

so the static block to register BouncyCastleProvider becomes:

```
static {
    Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```